# What is the most beautiful way to check a checkbox in jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I found many questions around this topic, but none is satisfying.

If you do:

```
$("#myCheckBox").attr("checked", "checked")
```

It does change the attribute and check the checkbox, but it doesn't trigger the "change" event. Doesn't look clean.

Or you could do:

```
$("#myCheckbox")[0].checked = true
```

But this is not beautiful.

What do you think ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The proper way is `$('#myCheckbox').prop('checked', true);` and you can then fire whatever events on it.

Since 1.6: http://api.jquery.com/prop/

Comment: But it doesn't seem to trigger the change event on the checkbox. Can you confirm ?

Comment: That's correct. There are a couple options: `$('#myCheckbox').prop('checked', true).change();` would be easiest. Otherwise you can do `$('#myCheckbox').prop('checked', true); handleCheckbox($('#myCheckbox'));` and handle checkbox would look at state, etc and do what it needs to do. `handleCheckbox` would be a function you write that would be your checkbox's `change` handler as well

Comment: @Blacksad setting a property or attribute value via javascript won't trigger the event regardless of what method you use. If you want an event to be fired, fire it. `$(element).trigger('change');`

Comment: Thanks guys, very clear answers. I thought that the change event was supposed to be triggered whatever the source of the event; I was wrong.

Answer (score 2):

One way to check the box is to use:

```
if (!$('#myCheckbox').prop("checked")){
  $('#mycheckbox').click();
}
```

assuming you still want the change event to trigger. Although this will need modifying if you want to check multiple boxes at once.